# styles multiple inheritance

Tags: android, styles

Is there any way to make a style inherit from multiple other styles, instead of just being limited to:

```
<style name="WidgetTextBase">
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>

<style name="BOSText" parent="WidgetTextBase">
    <item name="android:textColor">#051C43</item>
</style>
```

I would like BOSText to also inherit from:

```
<style name="WidgetTextHeader">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<style>
```

Comment: Is this maybe useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851175/how-to-apply-two-different-styles-to-one-element-in-android/4893402#4893402

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Styles do not support multiple inheritance (at least not as of Android 3.2).

The official [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#DefiningStyles) say:

> If you use the dot notation to extend a style, and you also include
> the parent attribute, then the parent styles override any styles
> inheritted through the dot notation.

Comment: Sorry, but You are wrong. See link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles

Comment: You misunderstood the question (see my comment on your answer below). You are right that you can construct style inheritance chains like A > B > C. The question though was whether you could do (A, B) > C. I.e., a style inherits from two independent inheritance chains.

Comment: Why is this set as the accepted answer? Styles DO support multiple inheritance.
The `parent` attribute gives you ONE inheritance and you can get a second inheritance from the name of the style, for instance: `<style name="Text.Bold" />` will inherit from the style called `Text`.
From the documentation: `Note: If you use the dot notation to extend a style, and you also include the parent attribute, then the parent styles override any styles inheritted through the dot notation.`

Comment: @Darwind This is wrong. You cannot inherit from multiple styles. When you use both dot notation and the parent attribute, **all** the styles from the dot notation is not applied **at all** regardless of the presence of the styles in the parent-attribute's style.

Comment: This answer is right. Excerpt from docs: "If you use the dot notation to extend a style, and you also include the parent attribute, then the parent styles override any styles inheritted through the dot notation."

Comment: Damn that's an unclear message.

Answer (score 11):

You can only inherit one style. However, you can also make the inherited style inherit from another style, and so on:

```
<style name="WidgetTextBase">
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>

<style name="WidgetTextHeader" parent="WidgetTextBase">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="BOSText" parent="WidgetTextHeader">
    <item name="android:textColor">#051C43</item>
</style>
```

You can't inherit more than one style, but you *can* set up an inheritance chain.

Answer (score 5):

For those who was looking for solution to just **merge** multiple different styles into one, you can use

```
public void applyStyle (int resId, boolean force)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme#applyStyle(int,%20boolean). 
And apply it that way

```
context.theme.applyStyle(R.style.MyAdditionalStyle, false)
```

Whenever you specify `true` as second argument, it overrides existing values in your theme, and when `false` it adds only non-overlapping values from `R.style.MyAdditionalStyle`

I haven't tested scenario with multiple styles yet, but according to docs you can achieve it. So that's how this approach can be used as an alternative to multiple inheritance.

Answer (score -4):

There is a parent attribute on the style tag that should let you inherit from other styles...

i.e.

```
<style name="CodeFont" parent="@style/WidgetTextBase">
   <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: The problem is, I would like to have multiple parent attributes.