# Can I inherit a style both the required Android parent, and my custom style?

Tags: android, styles, android-xml, multiple-inheritance, android-styles

Let's say I want to create a style for the action bar title text, that is required to inherit the Android base style:

```
<style name="AppActionBarTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_text</item>
</style>
```

But I also want to add these items that I'm already using in other places:

```
<style name="MyCustomStyle">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#44000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">3</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">3</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1.5</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Can I make the *AppActionBarTitleText* style inherit from both the required Android parent, and my custom style?

Or is there a way to include the attributes of my custom style (*MyCustomStyle*) into the action bar title text style (*AppActionBarTitleText*), without having to duplicate them?

P.S. I cannot inherit *MyCustomStyle* from *@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title*, because I'm also using the style for other TextView objects, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [styles multiple inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257656/styles-multiple-inheritance)