# Android make a button borderless by combine two styles doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a `back` button with the styles like:

```
 <style name="back_button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/frutiger_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/lightSaber</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:text">@string/back</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

But right now I already have one exited style:

```
  <style name="FrutigerLight16LightSaber">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/frutiger_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/lightSaber</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  </style>
```

So I want to add a new style with `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless` and `FrutigerLight16LightSaber`.

I tried two solutions by combing `.` and `parent`, but doesn't work.

**ONE**:

```
    <style name="FrutigerLight16LightSaber.Borderless" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    </style>
```

then

```
   <style name="back_button" parent="FrutigerLight16LightSaber.Borderless">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:text">@string/back</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

**in this way, I lost `FrutigerLight16LightSaber` style.**

**TWO**

```
   <style name="FrutigerLight16LightSaberBorderless" parent="FrutigerLight16LightSaber">
        <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>
    </style>
```

then

```
   <style name="back_button" parent="FrutigerLight16LightSaberBorderless">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:text">@string/back</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

**this way I lost `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless`.**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: how do you expect the margin done while both themes have same attr? u must lose one of them as each other override the value

Comment: @MoustafEL-Saghier Sorry, if I understood correctly, are you saying the `margin` is the attributes like `layout_marginTop` etc.? I actually just want to use the two existed style and combine them.

Comment: apologize, it is merging fk auto-correction

Comment: I was thought the dot `.` is an inheritance of one style, and  `parent` is another one.

Comment: well, what about the attrs that are common in parent and child? e.x parent has texTcolor x, a child has y ... u try to merge them what would be texTcolor? got it?

Comment: If so `child` override `parent` should be ok. I am not sure about Android style inheritance deeply, this idea is just basic on your comment.

Comment: yea, it is like what I said. the evidence on that when inheriting one other's style lost.

Comment: yeah, I agree, thanks @MoustafEL-Saghier

Comment: yw sir .. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<style name="FrutigerLight16LightSaber.Borderless" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/frutiger_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/lightSaber</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

And then use like below:

```
<style name="back_button" parent="FrutigerLight16LightSaber.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/back</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not what I expected. I want to use the existed `FrutigerLight16LightSaber` style, rather than move the attributes out of the style.

Comment: You can't target two parent at the same time

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not supported in android style xml For your reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/6789914/9584758